# Getting data from GridView after changing the DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, webforms

I am trying to add the column names of a gridview to a dropdown list.
The problem is when I change the datasource of the gridview, it returns empty.

I am not sure whether the event is working properly, as it does not work with/without it.
I wanted to use the DataBindComplete event, but I could not see it so I tried DataBound instead.

```
 private void BindTable()
    {
        if (ddTableSearch.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            tblCustomerTableAdapter customerAdapter = new tblCustomerTableAdapter(); 
            GridView2.DataSource = customerAdapter.GetData();
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
        else if (ddTableSearch.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            tblInvoiceTableAdapter invoiceAdapter = new tblInvoiceTableAdapter();
            GridView2.DataSource = invoiceAdapter.GetData();
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
        else if (ddTableSearch.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            tblEstimateTableAdapter estimateAdapter = new tblEstimateTableAdapter();
            GridView2.DataSource = estimateAdapter.GetData();
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void GridView2_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Populate dropdown with column names
        ddColumnSearch.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView2.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            ddColumnSearch.Items.Add(new ListItem(GridView2.Columns[i].ToString()));
        }
    }
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The databound event runs for each record in the gridview. So one issue is that each time you are clearing out the items you added before. Another issue is that you need to get the data from the EventArgs instead of from the gridview.columns since those are not there until after all the data is bound. I think all you need to do is get the data from the header row:

```
protected void GridView2_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Populate dropdown with column names
    if(e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Header) return; //only continue if this is hdr row
    ddColumnSearch.Items.Clear();
    foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
    {
        ddColumnSearch.Items.Add(new ListItem(cell.Text));
    }
}
```